# Layout For SQLite Resuts

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a layout that looks like below for every row it returns from my database (will be last 7 days). Any help would be appreciated.

XML I created

```
    <QuickContactBadge
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/date"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                  android:text="date"/>

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/temp"
               android:layout_width="150dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/date"
               android:layout_below="@+id/date"
               android:gravity="center_vertical"
               android:text="temp" />

           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fertile"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/notes"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/temp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="fertile" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/notes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/temp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/temp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="notes" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Can someone show me how to loop through the sql to get the layout i desire?

```
            public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        }       

         @Override
         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);

            //Get data from SQL
            SQLHelper entry = new SQLHelper(getActivity());
            entry.open();
            Cursor results = entry.getAllData();
            entry.close();



            return view;
         }

    }
```

SQL

```
public class SQLHelper {
    //Database information
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NFP";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //Table Information
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "charting";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "persons_name";
    public static final String KEY_CHARTING_DATE = "Date";
    public static final String KEY_CHARTING_TEMPERATURE = "temperature";
    public static final String KEY_CHARTING_STAMPS = "Stamps";
    public static final String KEY_CHARTING_FERTILE = "Fertile";
    public static final String KEY_CHARTING_NOTES = "Notes";
    public static final String KEY_CHARTING_PROC = "Proc";


    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private static SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public SQLHelper(Context c) {
        ourContext = c;
    }

            public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                                        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER  primary key AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                                        KEY_CHARTING_DATE + " TEXT primary key NOT NULL, " +
                                        KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                                        KEY_CHARTING_TEMPERATURE + " INTEGER, " +
                                        KEY_CHARTING_STAMPS  + " INTEGER, " +
                                        KEY_CHARTING_FERTILE + " TEXT, " +
                                        KEY_CHARTING_NOTES + " TEXT, " +
                                        KEY_CHARTING_PROC +  " ); "
                    );
        }

    public SQLHelper open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String date, String temperature, String fertile, String notes) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_CHARTING_DATE, date);
        cv.put(KEY_CHARTING_TEMPERATURE, temperature);
        cv.put(KEY_CHARTING_FERTILE, fertile);
        cv.put(KEY_CHARTING_NOTES, notes);
        return ourDatabase.insertOrThrow (DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }

    public String getData() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_CHARTING_DATE, KEY_CHARTING_TEMPERATURE, KEY_CHARTING_STAMPS, KEY_CHARTING_FERTILE, KEY_CHARTING_NOTES };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

        String result = "";

        int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHARTING_DATE);
        int iTemp = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHARTING_TEMPERATURE);
        int iStamps = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHARTING_STAMPS);
        int iFertile = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHARTING_FERTILE);
        int iNotes = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHARTING_NOTES);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result = result + "" + c.getString(iDate) + "/n" + c.getString(iTemp) + "/n" + c.getString(iStamps) + "/n" + c.getString(iFertile) + "/n" + c.getString(iNotes) + "|";
        }

        return result;
    }
    public Cursor getAllData() {


        String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_CHARTING_DATE, KEY_CHARTING_TEMPERATURE, KEY_CHARTING_STAMPS, KEY_CHARTING_FERTILE, KEY_CHARTING_NOTES };
        Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);


        return cursor;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard solution for this task, consisting of the following layers:

**Database layer**

I know nothing about the data source you are using: local or remote, so no advice here

**Content Provider, presenting data from your database.**

This is not that necessary, but allows usage of built-in loaders and cursorAdapters with minimal modification.

Your **custom Adapter** extending, say, SimpleCursorAdapter, that uses custom layout of a row shown on your example picture. Typically this layout is stored in a separate xml layout file. Adapter contains your logic of binding data from database cursor row to newly created row View.

Finally, **ListView** in your Fragment.
You set ListView's adapter to your Adapter.

Of course, this is quite a long way and not the only one, but the one with the minimum sweat and blood, I believe.

The details are too lengthy to cover in a single answer, so be sure to study corresponding tutorials:

[Custom Adapter and ListView](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/display-contact-badge.html)

[Content Provider on top of Sqlite database](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/writing-your-own-contentprovider/)

You should:
I. Wrap Content Provider around your database as in tutorial link above.
Result: class MyContentProvider.

```
 static {
    sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, DATABASE_TABLE, MATCH_ALL);

    projectionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    projectionMap.put(KEY_ROWID, KEY_ROWID);
    projectionMap.put(KEY_NAME, KEY_NAME);
    //...the same for other fields
    projectionMap.put(KEY_CHARTING_PROC, KEY_CHARTING_PROC);
 }


@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case MATCH_ALL:
            return MY_CONTENT_TYPE;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
    int count;
    SQLiteDatabase db = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case MATCH_ALL: {
            count = db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, whereArgs);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            return count;
        }
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }
}
//insert and update are just the same: copy from tutorial with the same changes

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case MATCH_ALL:
            qb.setTables(DATABASE_TABLE);
            qb.setProjectionMap(projectionMap);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }

    Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return c;
}
```

II. Create xml layout for single database row (you already have one). Result: entry.xml

III. Write class MyAdapter extending SimpleCursorAdapter, overriding it's newView() and bindView(). Also you shoud write class constructor.

```
    class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
    private int layout;

    public MyAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to); //deprecated, but used here for simplicity
        this.layout = layout; //your entry.xml id
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        Cursor c = getCursor();

        //creating row view from entry.xml
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

        bindView(v, context, c)    

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
        //get data from current cursor position
        int myCol = c.getColumnIndex("my_field");
        int myField = c.getInt(myCol);

        //find a widget in the view, inflated with your entry.xml
        ImageView imgType = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgMyField);
        if (imgType != null){
            if (myField == 0)
                imgType.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_zero);
            else
                imgType.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_non_zero);
        }

        return v;
    }
    }
```

Note, that newView()/bindView will be called automatically for each and every row in Cursor when you set Adapter for ListView or datasource changes.

IV. In your Fragment's onCreateView: View v

```
        //deprecated: only for simplicity
        //get database cursor from provider
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MyProvider.MY_CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, BaseColumns.ID + " ASC");
    String[] dataColumns = {/* you columns here*/ } ;
    adapter
            = new MyAdapter(
            this.getActivity(),                             // The Context for the ListView
            R.layout.entry,          // Points to the XML for a list item
            cursor,                           // The cursor to get items from
            dataColumns,
            null
    );
    ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter); //here list view is actually filled
```

If something is not working, check SearchableDictionary and NotePad samples from Android SDK

**Important note**: Don't stick with deprecated ManagedQuery after your listview gets to work. Use Loaders instead.

Comment: Is this all within the oncreateview? Sorry i'm new to this and i'm really trying to understand the concept.

Comment: I've tried to implement what i though i could but its crashing now... take a look.

Comment: Here's my complete code, what your asking me to do with those tutorials i've done something like already.

Comment: Ok. You have got SQLHelper, but haven't written your ContentProvider, wrapping it. You have got XML markup for your entry but you have no Adapter to fill your ListView with created entries. Finally, no ListView is filled in your HistoryFragment onCreateView.

Comment: Why is is the ContentProvider necessary?

Comment: Really it is not that necessary, but SimpleCursorAdapter (and then built-in loaders) works with ContentProvider. So to avoid implementing SimpleCursorAdapter functionality yourself, it's easier to write few simple methods wrapping your database class into ContentProvider

Comment: wow... this is making an answer very hard for me to find. I've read that tutorial and that tutorial is not very detailed for a new-be.

Comment: Not so! Rename your SqlHelper to e.g. class [SqlProvider extends ContentProvider] write static section  and implement-override: onCreate(), insert, delete, update, query, and getType by just copying from the tutorial, substituting table and field names. Moreover, NOTE_ID sections in switches can be safely cut out. You almost have it by now! I will include sample for query and static in the answer

Comment: What is MATCH_ALL defined as?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29943/discussion-between-alexei-burmistrov-and-jcaruso)

Comment: CHECK OUT http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597668/andriod-pulling-data-from-database where i think i've successuly done what you were talking about